# Why does printf leave an extra "%" after my output?

Tags: go

I have this piece of code

```
a := 32
fmt.Printf("%d", a)
```

the output is

```
32%
```

when anyone would expect

```
32
```

Could it be a terminal effect? I am using zsh.

Comment: [No it isn't](https://play.golang.org/p/LeeCKa9ocCp) (click Run).

Comment: I think the _%_ you got is from something else. Try to add a newline to your Printf.

Comment: Your she'll may add that percent sign to signify a missing newlines. Most shells highlight this extra character with a color.

Comment: @Peter has said the right thing. I was have the same problem and added "\n" at the end of the string. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that Printf doesn't add a newline. The '%' you are seeing is your bash / shell prompt.

Try this:

```
fmt.Printf("%d\n", 32)
```

The `\n` will add a newline, and your prompt will now be on the next line.

Comment: Yes, the matter of fact is I had already tried this out but I wanted to understand why do I need to add `\n` in the first place. Now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can’t reproduce your problem. Try it out on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nJUXhRGtDuO). You will see that there is no trailing %.

There must be another cause.

Note that you don’t have a newline at the end of the format string. The % could be from a subsequent printf.